# Cocoa NSNotificationCenter communication between apps failed

Tags: cocoa, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I need to communicate between two different console apps, Observer and Client.

In the Observer app I added this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
```

In the Client app I added this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(trackNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];

-(void)trackNotification:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    NSLog(@"trackNotification: %@", notif);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification name: %@", [notif name]);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification object: %@", [notif object]);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification userInfo: %@", [notif userInfo]);
}
```

but nothing happens. I read all the documentation, but I am brand new in Mac OS X.
Any ideas?

---

I read about the Distributed Notifications, I changed my code and now looks like this:
In the server side:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(trackNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];

-(void)trackNotification:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    NSLog(@"trackNotification: %@", notif);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification name: %@", [notif name]);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification object: %@", [notif object]);
    NSLog(@"trackNotification userInfo: %@", [notif userInfo]);
}
```

In the client side:

```
NSMutableDictionary *info;
info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[info setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];

[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification"
                                   object:nil
                                 userInfo:info 
                       deliverImmediately:YES];
```

I run both applications, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is the source code:
In the client side:

```
NSDictionary *user = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"John Doe", @"name", @"22222222222", @"phone", @"Dummy address", @"address", nil];

//Post the notification
NSString *observedObject = @"com.test.net";
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotificationName: @"Plugin Notification" object: observedObject userInfo: user deliverImmediately: YES];
```

In the server side

```
NSString *observedObject = @"com.test.net";
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver: self selector: @selector(receiveNotification:) name: @"Plugin Notification" object: observedObject];
```

receiveNotification definition

```
-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    NSlog(@"Hello");
}
```

In dealloc method

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: @"Plugin Notification" object: nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

`NSNotificationCenter` is only for notifications within one app. You want [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDistributedNotificationCenter). You can find more details in the [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html).

Comment: Thanks! I am going to take a look.